# InvokePattern is not supported for StartButton in Windows 10

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-10, ui-automation

I just started to study UIAutomation in powershell and i trying to automate clicking Start Button
And got this problem
My Script is throwing "Unsupported Pattern" error on this command:

```
$startButton.GetCurrentPattern([Windows.Automation.InvokePattern]::Pattern).Invoke()
```

Full code of my script:

```
Add-Type –AssemblyName UIAutomationClient
Add-Type –AssemblyName UIAutomationTypes

$root = [Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::RootElement
$condition = New-Object Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition([Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]::ClassNameProperty, "Start")
$startButton = $root.FindFirst([Windows.Automation.TreeScope]::Descendants, $condition)

$startButton.GetType()
$startButton.GetCurrentPattern([Windows.Automation.InvokePattern]::Pattern).Invoke()
```

Windows 10 20H2 10.0.19042
Powershell Core 7.1.3
How can the start button be pressed using UIAutomation?

thanks in advance

Added:

I don't understand. Similar code in C# (.NET Core 3.1) works

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.RootElement;
    System.Windows.Automation.Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Start");   
    AutomationElement startButtonUI = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condition);
    if (startButtonUI != null)
    {
        InvokePattern startBtnPattern = startButtonUI.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        startBtnPattern.Invoke();
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong in powershell?